# Sending and reading form kafka to mqtt exactly once

Tags: apache-kafka, mqtt

For transferring mqtt messages from and to kafka I use a mqtt connect worker,
 [similar to this one](http://docs.datamountaineer.com/en/latest/mqtt.html). The difference is, that I read and write to the mqtt broker. This is working quite fine.

```
┌────────────┐        ┌────────────┐               
│            │        │            │               
│    KAFKA   │        │     MQTT   │               
│   ┌────────│        │    BROKER  │               
│   │MQTT-Con│<──────>│            │               
└───┴────────┘        └────────────┘
```

As e next step, I want to switch from one single kafa broker a kafka cluster (for now, 2 kafka broker).

```
  ┌─────────────────────┐ 
  │    KAFKA CLUSTER    │
  │  ┌────────────┐     │                 
  │  │            │     │                 
  │  │  KAFKA A   │     │                 
  │  │   ┌────────│     │  ┌────────────┐               
  │  │   │MQTT-Con│<────│─>│            │               
  │  └───┴────────┘     │  │     MQTT   │               
  │                     │  │    BROKER  │
  │  ┌────────────┐  ┌──│─>│            │
  │  │            │  │  │  └────────────┘
  │  │  KAFKA  B  │  │  │                
  │  │   ┌────────│  │  │                 
  │  │   │MQTT-Con│<─┘  │                   
  │  └───┴────────┘     │                 
  └─────────────────────┘
```

My question is, what can i do, that i don't end up with the same message duplicated in kafka A and kafka B?

My mqtt messages should be QOS 2, exactly once.